# looking if a period is available or not

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm trying to make a booking system and I came across a mistake.
I have a starting date and a ending date, if I enter a date start en end that falls between a booking already made the system is saying that is not possible, however if I enter before and after a already occupied period the system accepts the booking

this how I check now

```
    `$db_check_result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ms_bookings WHERE ms_bookings_calid = '$propertyId' AND '$convertedstartdate' BETWEEN ms_bookings_startdate AND ms_bookings_enddate") or die(mysql_error());
```

if the result is greater than 0 then booking date is not possible and I do the samen with the departure date

```
$db_check_result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ms_bookings WHERE ms_bookings_calid = '$propertyId' AND '$convertedenddate' BETWEEN ms_bookings_startdate AND ms_bookings_enddate") or die(mysql_error());
```

again if the result is greater than 0 then booking is not possible

it works fine if new request falls within a already entered booking but when arrivaldate and departure date is before and after existing date the systems accepts

how can I solve this?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
**SO is not** a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service
___We try to fix your code, we do not write your code___

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it out of the way:

- Don't use `mysql_*` functions in any new code. The mysql extension has been removed from current PHP versions (starting with PHP 7.0). Use mysqli (note the "i") or pdo_mysql instead.
- Don't put any user data directly into your queries. This *will* lead to security problems in the future (SQL injection). Use placeholders instead.

That said, the third check you want is

```
SELECT * FROM ms_bookings
  WHERE ms_bookings_calid = :propertyId
    AND (ms_bookings_startdate BETWEEN :convertedstartdate AND :convertedenddate
         OR ms_bookings_enddate BETWEEN :convertedstartdate AND :convertedenddate)
```

However, you can combine all checks into a single simpler query:

```
SELECT * FROM ms_bookings
  WHERE ms_bookings_calid = :propertyId
    AND :convertedstartdate <= ms_bookings_enddate
    AND :convertedenddate >= ms_bookings_startdate
```

In order to not overlap, the new booking has to either start *after* the existing booking ends (`:convertedstartdate <= ms_bookings_enddate` will be false then), or it has to end *before* the existing booking starts (`:convertedenddate >= ms_booking_startdate` is false).

Comment: Please accept answers if they where helpful for you. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer